# Keeping a tkinter canvas origin centered

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, centering

Is it possible to keep the origin of a resizable tkinter.canvas centered without binding a Configure event handler to the canvas? I would like to achieve the same result as the following python script, but without using bind.

I gave up after searching for two hours. Is there a widget option I miss?

```
import tkinter
from PIL import ImageTk

def centerCanvasOrigin(e):
    root.update()
    cnv.scan_dragto(round(cnv.winfo_width()/2), round(cnv.winfo_height()/2), 1)
    
root = tkinter.Tk()
cnv = tkinter.Canvas()
cnv.pack(fill = tkinter.BOTH, expand = 1)
cnv.bind("<Configure>", centerCanvasOrigin)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="img/image.png")
cnv.create_image(0, 0, image = img)
centerCanvasOrigin(True) #i know, sry about this :)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This [documentation](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/canvas-methods.html) describes how do do fast scrolling by binding mouse events (see `.scan_dragto()` section). You may be able to something similar for sizing.

Comment: I do not wish to bind anything. The python code I posted does the job I want (with the Configure event), but I am interested if there were a solution other than bind.

Comment: If you want to follow the mouse's movements, you're going to need to bind mouse events… What do you have against binding anyway? Maybe this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I do not want to follow the mouse movements, I want the canvas origin be always in the middle of the application window, when the app window is stretched, as you can see when running the sample code (use an arbitrary png to be able to see it).The code above works perfectly, my question is if there were a way to avoid binding for this task, for performance reasons. Something like anchor=CENTER.

Comment: If you have a solution using `bind` that works, why don't you want to use `bind`?

Comment: WRT performance, I don't believe you don't need that `root.update()` call in the `centerCanvasOrigin()` function.

Comment: Yes, martineau, you are right, thank you for drawing my attention to it.
(I would still be interested in the answer to my original question.)
Brian Oakley, it's not that I don't want to use it, it's that I would like to avoid it. It seems to me that it is slow (I will try to confirm it when I have the time), and looks overly complicated compared to what it does. Of course, if it's not possible without bind, I will stick to my current solution.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to keep the origin of a resizable tkinter.canvas centered without binding a Configure event handler to the canvas?

No, it is not.